# Linux: How do I set the working directory of an application?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, komodo-edit

So I am using Komodo edit, and it thinks that my current directory is /home/username1/  Yet my files are in /home/username1/workspaces/ruby/project1

Why won't Komodo recognize that my working directy is that of the current file? Same with situation when I use Komodo Edit to launch a command ("ruby [complete path+file name]"), ruby can't find its require dependencies unless I give a complete path because it too seems to think it is working out of /home/username1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: http://community.activestate.com/faq/komodo-file-locations

You can use a completely custom Komodo user data directory by setting the KOMODO_USERDATADIR environment variable. I.e. export KOMODO_USERDATADIR=/tmp/komodoide51

You can use similar approach with ruby - look in the ENVIRONMENT section in the man file: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ruby